# Camera global rotation clamping issue Unity3D

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, rotation, global, clamp

I have a problem, I'm making an smooth camera movement script, and I can't figure out how to clamp correctly camera rotation.

Actually, camera is a child of player object.

When WASD is pressed the player is rotated, but the camera doesn't follow this rotation because of the script.

```
            var mouseDelta = new Vector2(Input.GetAxisRaw("Mouse X"), Input.GetAxisRaw("Mouse Y"));

            mouseDelta = Vector2.Scale(mouseDelta, CursorSensitivity); //new Vector2(CursorSensitivity.x * smoothing.x, CursorSensitivity.y * smoothing.y));

            if (m_doSmooth)
            {
                _smoothMouse.x = Mathf.Lerp(_smoothMouse.x, mouseDelta.x, 1f / smoothing.x);
                _smoothMouse.y = Mathf.Lerp(_smoothMouse.y, mouseDelta.y, 1f / smoothing.y);

                // Find the absolute mouse movement value from point zero.
                _mouseAbsolute += _smoothMouse;
            }
            else
                _mouseAbsolute += mouseDelta;

            if (clampInDegrees.x > 0)
                _mouseAbsolute.x = Mathf.Clamp(_mouseAbsolute.x, -clampInDegrees.x, clampInDegrees.x);

            if (clampInDegrees.y > 0)
                _mouseAbsolute.y = Mathf.Clamp(_mouseAbsolute.y, -clampInDegrees.y, clampInDegrees.y);

            Camera.transform.rotation = Quaternion.AngleAxis(-_mouseAbsolute.x, Vector3.up) //transform.InverseTransformDirection(Vector3.up))
                * Quaternion.AngleAxis(_mouseAbsolute.y, Vector3.right);
```

Well, the problem is easy, the clamped rotation values are global, because we set  `Camera.transform.rotation` instead of `Camera.transform.localRotation`.

And this happens: [Link to video](https://i.gyazo.com/6ff177ff764e4a63a82954922391c6ff.mp4)

The script clamps values according to player rotation.

So if we have a rotation (eulerAngle) on the player on the X axis of 90 degrees, and clamp value is from 90 to -90, the clamped rotation will be 0, 180, instead of -90, 90.

But if I change from `rotation` to `localRotation` this happens: [Link to video](https://i.gyazo.com/df95b4ff61f29f91fe0196103d8ba7f3.mp4)

I also tried the following:

```
            Vector3 euler = Camera.transform.eulerAngles;

            if (clampInDegrees.x > 0)
                euler.x = ClampAngle(euler.x, -clampInDegrees.x, clampInDegrees.x);

            if (clampInDegrees.x > 0)
                euler.y = ClampAngle(euler.y, -clampInDegrees.y, clampInDegrees.y);

            Camera.transform.eulerAngles = euler;
```

After setting `localRotation`... But this only make weird things. Like for example, when reaching the min clamp value at rotating the clamp returns the max clamp value.

Comment: Using common terms for these angles: **pitch** = elevation angle from horizontal plane (dependent on mouse Y), and **yaw** = horizontal rotation angle (anti-)clockwise from X-axis (dependent on mouse X). Pitch is easy to constrain - `[-90, +90]` degrees. Yaw is a little harder - it crosses the polar angle discontinuity at 180 degrees; it is easier to work with a rotated coordinate system in this case if you want to avoid the horrific math to handle this singularity.